# Want to find a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies these inequalities

Tags: functions, inequality

I want to find a function $f \in C^\infty([0,T])$ such that
$$0 < L \leq f \leq M$$
$$f' \geq C \geq K_1 + K_2M$$
where $K_1$ and $K_2$ are fixed positive constants and are given.

Is it possible to do this if one is given $L$ and $M$? If not, is it possible to do this when $L$ and $M$ can depend on $C$?

This should hold for any choice of $T$.

The presence of $M$ in the derivative condition makes it difficult.  I think it's not possible at least with a linear function w ithout having to restrict $T$.

Comment: Any such function has to satisfy $f(T)\ge L+T\cdot C$ so clearly if $C$ is too large, it will violate $f\le M$.

Comment: Why does it have to satisfy that?

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: $f(T)=f(0)+\int_0^T f^\prime(x)dx\ge L+\int_0^T C dx = L+C\cdot (T-0)$.

Comment: Oh ok thanks    ....

Comment: refresh the page, I fixed it as soon as I typed

Comment: OK so I guess then we must have $M$ and $L$ depend on $C$ somehow

Comment: Well, $M \leq (C-K_1)/K_2$ ...

Comment: I think it's not possible at least with a linear function w ithout having to restrict $T$